# Stop goto optimization g

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, g++

When writing asm code, there is a trick to slow down the code by a cycle or two by telling the cpu to explicitly jump to the next instruction.  I was thinking to do something similar using C++ templates.  Here's my code:

```
template <unsigned int c>
inline void adelay()
{
  goto x;
x:
  adelay<c-1>();
}

template <>
inline void adelay<0>()
{
}
```

Although the idea seems sound, the optimizer appears to be getting in the way by removing the jmp code.  Any ideas how this could be implemented?

**Background**

The reason for wanting to do this is to slow down the code of a micro-controller such that it outputs a light beam pulse at a very specific frequency.  This is a very specialized use, and is not a common except in low level hardware access such as writing drivers or programming micro-controllers.  Even then I try and avoid such things when at all possible.  Unfortunately, this cannot always be avoided.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Any code-based slowdown like this is, almost certainly, the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I wish I had the problem of trying to slow down my code

Comment: Depending on the compiler you can put asm straight into C++, (at least with Visual C++)

Comment: I'm programing a micro-controller.

Comment: Yeah, tried the asm route without joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help all.  Instead of using jmp instructions, I went with nop instructions:

```
template <unsigned int c>
inline void adelay() 
{
  asm("nop");
  adelay<c-1>();
}

template <>
inline void adelay<0>()
{
}
```

At one point I used referencing a volatile variable which worked at a slightly courser granularity:

```
static volatile int _adelay = 0;
template <unsigned int c>
inline void adelay()
{
  _adelay;
  adelay<c-1>();
}

template <>
inline void adelay<0>()
{
}
```

That may be useful when I'm running low on memory.

Thanks again! :)

Adrian

Answer (score 2):

That's what optimizer should do - optimize, including removal of non-functional code.
Either disable the optimizations completely in your compiler options or use other methods to slow your program, there are plenty of APIs that allow you to sleep for a defined time.

Comment: They are not fine enough.  I'm programing a micro-controller.

FYI, I am using such methods for coarse delay control.

Comment: Also didn't want extraneous labels lying around.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this attribute:

```
template <>
inline void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) adelay<0>()
{
}
```

Which should prevent the optimization. Although as others have mentioned there are probably better ways but if this is purely for learning purposes than all good. I usually use [this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) to verify assembler output really quick or when I am not at a command line.

Comment: Removing optimisation like that introduces extra code.  However, that web site is great!  It did allow me to remember the nop instruction.

Comment: Hmmm, have solution, but this site won't let me post it as an answer.  Grrrr.